# unreal tournament 3: reverse engineering lan browser udp broadcasts

Tags: network-programming, udp, protocols, reverse-engineering

there [exist](http://wiki.unrealadmin.org/UT3_query_protocol) [some](http://web2.gservers.de/~phillip/projects/clqp/ut2004/docs/unrealtournament-2k4-demo-lan-browser-tcp-dump.txt) resources explaining details about the unreal (tournament 3's) network protocol.

i am specifically interested in the games lan broadcasting protocol on which i can't find any material. i'd be very thankful if anyone of you could point me somewhere so that i can stop this tedious task.

wireshark reported the following:

**discovery broadcast packet** (sent by client to 255.255.255.255:14001)

```
Data: 05014d5707db53512a690835e4fae171

ff ff ff ff ff ff 7c 6d 62 8c 3c 7f 08 00 45 00   ......|mb.<...E.
00 2c 12 a1 00 00 40 11 00 00 0a 0a 0a aa ff ff   .,....@.........
ff ff 36 b1 36 b1 00 18 14 dd 05 01 4d 57 07 db   ..6.6.......MW..
53 51 2a 69 08 35 e4 fa e1 71                     SQ*i.5...q
```

**server response broadcast** (sent by server to 255.255.255.255:14001)

```
Data: 05014d5707db53522a690838e4fae1710a0a0aab00001e61...

ff ff ff ff ff ff 08 00 27 07 25 89 08 00 45 00   ........'.%...E.
01 54 00 00 40 00 40 11 24 e5 0a 0a 0a ab ff ff   .T..@.@.$.......
ff ff 36 b1 36 b1 01 40 86 61 05 01 4d 57 07 db   ..6.6..@.a..MW..
53 52 2a 69 08 38 e4 fa e1 71 0a 0a 0a ab 00 00   SR*i.8...q......
1e 61 00 00 00 10 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 00 00   .a..............
00 00 01 01 01 01 01 01 01 00 01 00 00 00 00 00   ................
00 00 00 00 00 00 05 3a 75 74 33 3a 00 00 00 0c   .......:ut3:....
00 00 80 0b 00 00 00 02 01 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   ................
03 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 06 00   ................
00 00 01 01 00 00 00 07 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00   ................
08 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 09 00 00 00 00 01 00   ................
00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0b 00 00 00 00   ................
01 00 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 0d 00 00   ................
00 01 01 00 00 00 0e 00 00 00 01 01 00 00 00 08   ................
40 00 00 01 04 00 00 00 0d 57 41 52 2d 41 76 61   @........WAR-Ava
6c 61 6e 63 68 65 02 40 00 00 02 04 00 00 00 25   lanche.@.......%
55 54 47 61 6d 65 43 6f 6e 74 65 6e 74 2e 55 54   UTGameContent.UT
4f 6e 73 6c 61 75 67 68 74 47 61 6d 65 5f 43 6f   OnslaughtGame_Co
6e 74 65 6e 74 02 10 00 00 f8 01 00 00 00 00 01   ntent...........
10 00 00 f9 01 00 00 00 14 01 10 00 00 f7 01 00   ................
00 00 0b 01 40 00 00 03 04 00 00 00 00 02 10 00   ....@...........
01 05 01 00 00 00 00 01 40 00 00 04 04 00 00 00   ........@.......
00 02                                             ..
```

the discovery packet differs in some bytes on every request but has basically the same structure each time.

the response contains the request's bytes at the beginning, some garbage and apparently a bunch of actually useful bits.

how would i go on parsing the response?
does the *garbage* contain useful data, how can i find out?
he who has some experience on that matter would have what advise?